# how to remove rows from multidimensional array cakephp

Tags: arrays, cakephp, multidimensional-array

I added some item inside cart session(Array) but i want to remove 1 rows for that i wrote following code but that is not working for me.

```
public function deletecart() {
$this->loadModel("Product");
    if($this->Session->check('cart') AND count($this->Session->read('cart'))>0) 
    {
        foreach ($this->Session->read('cart') as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['0']['Product']['id'] == "12") {
        unset($this->Session->read('cart')[$key]); 
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my session debug value

```
array(
    '[0]' => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Product' => array(
                'id' => '8',
                'category' => 'Pendant',
            )
        )
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        (int) 0 => array(
            'Product' => array(
                'id' => '12',
                'category' => 'Pendant'
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't unset session key value like this. You will have to store Session key value in a temporary variable.

```
$sessionArr = $this->Session->read('cart');
foreach ($sessionArr as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['0']['Product']['id'] == "12") {
// Unset key 
        unset($sessionArr[$key]); 
    }
}

// Assign $sessionArr value to cart key 
$this->Session->write('cart',$sessionArr);
```

Comment: @prameshwer . I've tested it in my pc and it is working. Share your code.